# Red5 : Deploy while Red5 is running (WAR deployment fail : org.springframework.beans.factory. BeanDefinitionStoreException) while normal deploy ok)

Tags: deployment, war, red5

I need to be able to deploy while Red5 is running. The only solution I know is to use WAR file and put it in the folder : webapp.

Is there any other way ?

I'm using Red 5 v0.8. And I exported a WAR file using Eclipse 3.4.

I can deploy my webapp. However when I export it as a WAR file, I have
an error message and it creates an empty folder (cf see error message at the end).
When I install the samples given with Red5, the WAR deploys correctly.
I tested it by mapping exactly the same files of SOSample and my
webapp for WEB-INF (I've just changed the name of the webapps), but
the problem persists.

I tried Project -> Clean ..., deleted the webapps folder before
copying the war files into it. I checked that when it's deployed normally
that's the correct files. Still, the same behaviour.

It might be a simple thing but still I don't much about Spring, I must
miss something simple.

Thank you in advance for any help you could give me,

Fabio

---

### ----------------------  Error message

[INFO] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-1] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Applicati
on root: C:/eclipse/applications/Red5/webapps
[WARN] [Launcher:/Addition] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - default.c
ontext bean was not found in context: red5.core
Exception in thread "Launcher:/Addition" org.springframework.beans.factory.
BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern
 [/WEB-INF/red5-*.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Servl
etContext resource [/WEB-INF/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exi
st
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.load
BeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.load
BeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtain
FreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
       at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$2.run(TomcatLoader.java:733)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/] ca
nnot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
       at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL
(ServletContextResource.java:130)
       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolv
er.isJarResource(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:406)
       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolv
er.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:338)
       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolv
er.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:276)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getRes
ources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1018)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
       ... 7 more

-------------------------- Code Source -----------------------
package org.red5.core;
import org.red5.server.adapter.MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter;

public class Application extends MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter {

```
   public Double add(Double a, Double b) {
           return a+b;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When deploy your webapp, have you add all external JARs under ***/YourRed5InstallPath/lib*** ？

Have a look at [CreatingRed5Projects](http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Red5Plugin/CreatingRed5Projects).